# MySql Galera Cluster Status

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, galera

i would like to create a file a proofscript and check the status of galera cluster with javascript or php. How can i do that ? Is that possible with javascript or php ?

I have not found any code for this topic

Comment: What "status" value are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

[show global variables like 'wsrep_local_state'](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera-cluster-status-variables/#wsrep_local_state) as a query will return a 1 row, 1 column result with that value.

This can be written in any SQL capable language.